# Split escape sequences in ruby from linux terminal emulator

Tags: ruby, linux, io, terminal, emulation

I'm reading escape sequences in Ruby from standard input in Linux terminal emulator, including mouse tracking data (`input=STDIN.sysread(100)`).

How do I split the received string? Or is there a possibility to read the data already splitted?

Example:
`input` contains `"\e[Hs\e[35;12;74M"`.

How do I get

```
[
    "\e[H",          # pos-key pressed
    "s",             # s-key pressed
    "\e[35;12;74M"   # mouse moved
]
```

?

I think it should be possible to parse the string and I don't understand why I can't find any information about that.

Many thanks!

Comment: Do you have a list of the possible key encodings here? Parsing that out with a regular expression and `scan` seems possible, but without details on the allowed values that's hard to pin down. Also, rather than re-inventing the wheel have you tried using the [Ruby Curses library](https://github.com/ruby/curses) which does all of this for you?

Comment: Every value should be allowed. Only tput is available. I don't use other parts of curses or ncurses because of compatibility and other issues. Is the only possibility to write a parser including all possible escape sequences? Isn't there a reliable possibility to read those inputs already split? I mean, they are split before written into the standard input, aren't they?

Comment: What "compatibility and other issues"? There's support in the Ruby core, this is not some exotic dependency. You've got a huge job ahead if you're going to write a parser for this. They're not split on input, they're fed through as a stream. The terminal understands them, and your code will have to as well if you assume responsibility fro that. Hence: **curses**.

Comment: I think the inputs are written one after another into the stream. Only the standard input merges them into one string. Curses is not flexible enough and it's slow I heard.

Comment: I already reached my goal without curses. I need a solution for this only to correct tiny inaccuracies.

Comment: The way these things go the first 80% is easy. The remaining 80% is very, very hard. I think you underestimate the complexity here.

Comment: Only 0.01% is remaining. Maybe it isn't worth correcting. I'll have a look at the curses implementation of ruby. Thank you.